# How can we detect & remove variables with inbetween NAs and calculate the ACF on multiple time series?

Tags: r, tidyverse, tsibble, imputets, tidyverts

Here is my toy time series data:

```
library(tidyverse); library(tsibble); library(feasts)

df <- tibble::tribble(
         ~date,     ~A,     ~B,     ~C,
   "1/31/2010",     NA,  0.017,     NA,
   "2/28/2010",     NA,  0.027,     NA,
   "3/31/2010",     NA,  0.003,  0.003,
   "4/30/2010", -0.022,  0.018,  0.018,
   "5/31/2010", -0.036,   0.02,   0.02,
   "6/30/2010", -0.046,  0.023,  0.023,
   "7/31/2010",     NA,  0.027,  0.027,
   "8/31/2010", -0.022,  0.008,  0.008,
   "9/30/2010",  0.059, -0.003, -0.003,
  "10/31/2010",  0.024,  0.058,  0.058,
  "11/30/2010",     NA,  0.023,     NA,
  "12/31/2010",     NA,  0.014,     NA
  )
```

I want to calculate autocorrelation (acf) of multiple time series. Ignoring the imputation part, I need to:

1. Remove the variables with inbetween NAs (not those at the start and end of the time series) like NA on 7/31/2010 for A. So in this case, remove variable A.
2. Calculate the auto correlations potentially using ACF function from feasts package on B and C.

I started here and got stuck:

```
df %>%
      mutate(date = mdy(date)) %>% 
      pivot_longer(cols = -date) %>% 
      as_tsibble(key = name, index = date) %>% 
      ACF()
```

The expected output would have autocorrelations of every possible series by lag. Like B will have 10-11 values for 10 lags and same for series B

Comment: *"Remove the variables with inbetween NAs "* Can you explain what you mean by that? What variable? Do you want to omit that specific time point from `A`? Do you want to omit `A` alltogether?

Comment: Omit A alltogether. I am finding it difficult to detect variables with inbetween NAs.

Comment: Is it possible to have a variable with NA only at the start and NOT at the end? If so, do you remove them?

Comment: @Geet You can achieve the first part using `rle` (see my answer); not sure what you expect for part 2. What is your expected output?

Comment: @sotos Yes, it is possible to have a variable with NA only at the start and NOT at the end and I will not remove that as I would want to remove only the variables that have in between NAs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Regarding part 1

We can make use of `rle`. Let's define a concise custom function `has_middle_NA`

```r
has_middle_NA <- function(x) {
    rl <- rle(is.na(x))$values
    any(rl[-c(1, length(rl))])
}
```

Then

```r
df %>%
    group_by(date) %>%
    select_if(~ !has_middle_NA(.x)) %>%
    ungroup()
## A tibble: 12 x 3
#   date            B      C
#   <chr>       <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 1/31/2010   0.017 NA
# 2 2/28/2010   0.027 NA
# 3 3/31/2010   0.003  0.003
# 4 4/30/2010   0.018  0.018
# 5 5/31/2010   0.02   0.02
# 6 6/30/2010   0.023  0.023
# 7 7/31/2010   0.027  0.027
# 8 8/31/2010   0.008  0.008
# 9 9/30/2010  -0.003 -0.003
#10 10/31/2010  0.058  0.058
#11 11/30/2010  0.023 NA
#12 12/31/2010  0.014 NA
```

This removes all columns with `NA`s that are not leading or trailing.

#### Regarding part 2

It's still not really clear to me what you're trying to do with ACF based on the data you give; but perhaps this helps.

The key is to treat your data as monthly data, ignoring the day. We can then:

- Convert your data into monthly data using `zoo::yearmon`,
- Select those columns that have no `NA`s "in the middle",
- Convert from wide-to-long and create a `tsibble` from every column,
- Use `feasts::ACF` to calculate the ACF for every column and store the result in a `list` column of `tsibble`s

```r
library(tsibble)
library(tidyverse)
library(feasts)
library(zoo)
df <- df %>%
    mutate(date = as.yearmon(date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")) %>%
    group_by(date) %>%
    select_if(~ !has_middle_NA(.x)) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    pivot_longer(-date) %>%
    group_by(name) %>%
    nest() %>%
    mutate(
        data = map(data, as_tsibble),
        ACF = map(data, ACF))
## A tibble: 2 x 3
## Groups:   name [2]
#  name  data               ACF
#  <chr> <list>             <list>
#1 B     <tsibble [12 × 2]> <tsibble [10 × 2]>
#2 C     <tsibble [12 × 2]> <tsibble [7 × 2]>
```

Comment: Thanks for the 1st part. Regarding 2, I want to calculate the auto correlations on B and C potentially using ACF function from feasts package.

Comment: @Geet Yes I'm familiar with what ACF is. The question is: What do you expect as your expected output? Want to you want to return?

Comment: @Geet Additionally, `feasts::ACF` will complain about gaps in your data. How do you want to deal with that?

Comment: Yeah, I am actually not sure, what to do about that as well :(. May be the other acf function from stats will help, right?

Comment: And, I guess, if it that's possible, then the expected output would be Autocorrelations of every possible series by lag. Like B will have 10-11 values for 10 lags and same for series B, and so on.

Comment: @Geet Base R's `acf` will also complain about gaps (or rather: missing values). So thats not going to help. I'm not sure whether what you're asking makes sense.

Comment: @Geet Please take a look at my edit. You can calculate an ACF if you treat your data as monthly data (ignoring the day component).